# Create multiple aws_cloudformation_stack based on parametrized name with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is it possible to create multiple CloutFormation stacks with one `aws_cloudformation_stack` resource definition in terraform, based on parametrized name ?
I have the following resources defined and I would like to have a stack per `app_name`, `app_env` `build_name` combo:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "sam_deploy_object" {
  bucket = var.sam_bucket
  key    = "${var.app_env}/${var.build_name}/sam_template_${timestamp()}.yaml"
  source = "../.aws-sam/sam_template_output.yaml"
  etag   = filemd5("../.aws-sam/sam_template_output.yaml")
}
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "subscriptions_sam_stack" {
  name         = "${var.app_name}---${var.app_env}--${var.build_name}"
  capabilities = ["CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM", "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"]
  template_url = "https://${var.sam_bucket}.s3-${data.aws_region.current.name}.amazonaws.com/${aws_s3_bucket_object.sam_deploy_object.id}"
}
```

When I run `terraform apply` when `build_name` name changes, the old stack gets deleted and a new one created, however I would like to keep the old stack and create a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to define your variable `build_name` as a list. Then, when you create new build, you just append them to the list, and create stacks with the help of [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) to iterate over the build names.

For example, if you have the following:

```
variable "app_name" {
  default = "test1"
}

variable "app_env" {
  default = "test2"
}


variable "build_name" {
  default = ["test3"]
}

resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "subscriptions_sam_stack" {

  for_each     = toset(var.build_name) 
  
  name         = "${var.app_name}---${var.app_env}--${each.value}"
  capabilities = ["CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM", "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"]
  template_url = "https://${var.sam_bucket}.s3-${data.aws_region.current.name}.amazonaws.com/${aws_s3_bucket_object.sam_deploy_object.id}"  
}
```

Then if you want second build for the stack, you just extend `variable "build_name"`:

```
variable "build_name" {
  default = ["test3", "new_build"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! This could work. My build names are hashed git branch names so they are pretty dynamic. I could write the current branch name into a file before any `terraform apply` call (to keep a record of which branch has been deployed) , and feed that file contents into the variable . Or do you think there is a better way to do this ?

Comment: @HIT_girl There is probably a better way, involving some CI/CD pipeline, but at present I'm not sure how to do it. You can make a new question specifically for this issue with relevant details, examples and description if you want.