# Multiple aws_cloudformation_stack resources based on dynamic name values with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

This is a follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432105/create-multiple-aws-cloudformation-stack-based-on-parametrized-name-with-terrafo)
I would like to create multiple `aws_cloudformation_stack` resources with names based on `git branch`. Git branches would be used to test different versions of `CloudFormation` stacks and can be deployed by several engineers (hence I would need to have the engineers access remote terraform state).
I would like to ensure that each deployed branch has its stack, but when branches update code the stacks would get updated (stacks destroyed and recreated)
One suggestion was to use `for_each` to create multiple resources.
To do that I would probably need to write branch names to a file (before `terraform apply`, and then read it into a list variable so `for_each` could iterate over the list.

However, I'd like to see if is there a better way to achieve this ?

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "subscriptions_sam_stack" {
  for_each = toset(split(",", file("deployed_git_hashes.txt")))
  name         = "${var.app_name}---${var.app_env}--${each.value}"
  capabilities = ["CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM", "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"]

  template_url = "https://${var.sam_bucket}.s3-${data.aws_region.current.name}.amazonaws.com/${aws_s3_bucket_object.sam_deploy_object.id}"
}
```

`deployed_git_branches.txt` looks like this:

```
branch1, branch2, branch3
```

Comment: I would prefer using a `external` data source to retrieve the git tags instead of relying on a file: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source . Do you want to redeploy your code whenever a new branch is created / removed?

Comment: Thanks @luk2302, I'll take a look at `external` option. The code doesn't have to automatically redeploy when git branches created/updated/removed. This would be done with CI (I think), after successful tests. But I do want to be able to redeploy with `terraform apply` after there are either code changes in my current branch or I'm in a new branch. The reason I was thinking to keep branch hashes in a file is for keeping history of what has been deployed so far